# How to take name from file with specific extension and use it as variable in batch script?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

Can anyone tell me how to take name from specific file with specific extension (.pdf) and use it as variable? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%f in (*.pdf) do ( 
    set x=%%f
)
echo %x%
```

Assuming there's only one PDF in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and what if i have multiple files with the same name?

Comment: Then your question doesn't make sense. How can you make five filenames into one variable? Inside the loop, the `%%f` is each filename... so probably just use that.

Comment: Okie, can tell me then how to use filename but withous extension? Just bare filename... Thanks in advance...

Comment: I can parrot the help back to you: `for /?` -->  `%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only`, therefore `set x=%%~nf`.